# What is the content type check to see if uploaded macro enabled spreadsheet contains a virus macro?

Tags: java, content-type

It is required to upload macro(MS Office) enabled spreadsheets(.xls,.xlsx,.xlsm,.ods etc) on server. It can contain macros. But I need to inhibit upload of those files which contain a virus macro.

What is the content type check for this?

Comment: Any macro can be a virus.

Comment: yes, how to differentiate? Kindly help with your skills and experience to come to a solution.

Comment: Determining whether a macro has malicious intent is equivalent to the Halting Problem.  You can't do that.

Comment: You need anti-virus software for that, that can scan the files and recognize known viruses. Unknown viruses would still slip through however.

Comment: downvote reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider relaxing the constraints of the problem statement a bit. Instead of detecting if a macro is virus or not use a divide and conquer approach.

If the macro is not user-written, but instead just uses a template that has this macro, then you can take MD5 or SHA1 signatures of these macros and ascertain that these are valid macros.

If these are user-written macros, then you will have to open a dialog with your end-users and build a dictionary of finitely many macros that you can allow to be uploaded. You can use the same technique mentioned above.